# npm devuelve "no encontrado" para paquete instalado en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Tengo un package.json que funciona correctamente en local.
Lo he subido al servidor, realizado el #npm install, se ha creado la carpeta node_modules y  al listar los paquetes instalados en npm aparece, por ejemplo "nodemon"

├── helmet@4.6.0

├─┬ nodemon@2.0.7

Pero ocurre que al llamar al comando #nodemon -v o #helmet -v la consola devuelve -bash: nodemon: no se encontró la orden

Tampoco puedo inciar mi .js con el comando #nodemon server.js sin embargo si inicia con  #node server.js  y no da ningún error para el requerimiento de helmet

Alguna idea de qué puede ocurrir?

Comment: No es usual usar nodemon en un servidor, pues nodemon es utilizado como dependencia de desarrollo y no de producción

Comment: Y qué es recomendado usar en producción?

Comment: pues nada, solo inicias tu tu servidor con el comando `node index,js`

Comment: Ya, pero entonces no cambia si cambio el archivo. Qué opinas de Forever?

Comment: a que te refieres con *"si cambio el archivo"*?, y no te puedo decir nada de *Forever* pues no lo he utilizado

Comment: Nodemon te inicia el server.js y lo mantiene, incluso pendiente de ediciones del archivo. Si inicias sólo con node, en cuanto cierras la consola el servidor se detiene. Forever es otro paquete que inicia el .js, lo vigila y lo logea automáticamente.

Comment: si pero si lo tienes en un servidor no tienes por que usar nodemon, pues no vas a hacer cambios varias veces.

Comment: Creo que ya saben lo que es nodemon, la observación que el te hace no es sobre eso, sino que estando en producción esos archivos no deberían cambiarse desde el mismo servidor, por eso mismo hay una etapa de desarrollo, Si necesitas editar un archivo hazlo sobre una copia en desarrollo y luego lo reemplazas. Si bien la respuesta que te dieron abajo es una respuesta válida, no es conveniente hacerlo en tu contexto, porque no deberías hacerlo así. No es la manera adecuada. Pides solucionar una pregunta que tienes por algo que no deberías hacer.

Comment: Como estas publicando tu app? En que servicio? Puedes poner tu `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se soluciona instalando los paquetes globalmente, por ej:

```
#npm install nodemon -g
```

Si quisiera correr el server.js con nodemon sin instalarlo globalmente puede hacerse iniciando con el comando:

```
#npx nodemon serve.js
```